# How come I'm getting this Django error?

Tags: python, django, templates, pagination

I installed an app called Django-notification, which uses Django-pagination. However, it can't find the Django_pagination template tags!

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /notifications
Exception Value: 'pagination_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library pagination_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.pagination_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.pagination_tags,django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.pagination_tags,pinax.templatetags.templatetags.pagination_tags
```

Why? I installed Django-pagination already. It's in my site-packages: `django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.6.egg`

Next, I put "pagination" in my INSTALLED_APPS.

I even imorted pagination in my views.py. Although I doubt that'll make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, have you called `{% load pagination_tags %}` in your template?

From [django's documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

> The app that contains the custom tags must be in INSTALLED_APPS in
>   order for the {% load %} tag to work.
>   This is a security feature: It allows
>   you to host Python code for many
>   template libraries on a single host
>   machine without enabling access to all
>   of them for every Django installation.
>
> There's no limit on how many modules you put in the templatetags
>   package. Just keep in mind that a {%
>   load %} statement will load
>   tags/filters for the given Python
>   module name, not the name of the app.
>
> To be a valid tag library, the module must contain a module-level
>   variable named register that is a
>   template.Library instance...